# (SOLVED) How to enable HiDPI scaling in the pantheon greeter?

Tags: release-loki, greeter, pantheon, release-juno, hidpi

My pantheon greeter runs at 3840x2160@60Hz but all elements are too small.
On the desktop I managed to enable

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```

what did the job of enlarging gui elements on UHD resolution.

How can I enable HiDPI scaling in the pantheon greeter?

My System:

```
System:    Host: LinuxLab2 Kernel: 4.8.0-53-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Gnome  (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) Distro: elementary 0.4.1 loki
Machine:   Mobo: ASUSTeK model: Z170-DELUXE v: Rev 1.xx Bios: American Megatrends v: 1902 date: 06/27/2016
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-6700K (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 32064
           clock speeds: max: 4300 MHz 1: 799 MHz 2: 799 MHz 3: 799 MHz 4: 800 MHz 5: 800 MHz 6: 800 MHz
           7: 799 MHz 8: 800 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA Device 1b80 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 3840x2160@59.94hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 1080/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 381.22 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 NVIDIA Device 10f0 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1 Sound: ALSA v: k4.8.0-53-generic
           Card-2 Intel Sunrise Point-H HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k bus-ID: 00:1f.6
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Broadcom BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter driver: wl bus-ID: 07:00.0
           IF: wlp7s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-3: Intel I211 Gigabit Network Connection driver: igb v: 5.3.0-k port: c000 bus-ID: 0b:00.0
           IF: enp11s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 2575.6GB (2.5% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 256.1GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 1024.2GB
           ID-3: /dev/sdc model: WDC_WD1002FAEX size: 1000.2GB
           ID-4: /dev/sdd model: KINGSTON_SH100S3 size: 120.0GB
           ID-5: /dev/sde model: KINGSTON_SV300S3 size: 120.0GB
           ID-6: USB /dev/sdf model: SNA size: 55.0GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 110G used: 60G (58%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdd1
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C gpu: 0.0:54C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 0
Info:      Processes: 257 Uptime: 3:01 Memory: 3091.1/32089.9MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after all this waiting I found a quite good solution for this problem:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml
```

Change the default value to 2 (or your desired scale factor):

```
<key name="scaling-factor" type="u">
<default>2</default>
```

now run the command

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

Boom, and my greeter got scaled x2 times, just as the desktop already have been.
Thought it will scale my desktop x2 times additionally, but it didn't :D